Why my Solaris terminal is "truncated"?
Strange situation
On Linux my terminal works fine, in this example after man wget...

On Solaris 10...
##IMAGE START HERE##

##IMAGE END HERE##
As you can see the output is truncated in the middle, when root@solaris10 appear.
This is my settings for terminal on Linux
stty -g
4500:5:bf:8a3b:3:1c:7f:15:4:0:1:0:11:13:1a:0:12:f:17:16:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0

Those on Solaris
stty -g
500:5:f00bf:8a3b:3:1c:7f:15:4:0:0:0:11:13:1a:19:12:f:17:16:0:0:1:1:0:00:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0

More friendly output stty -a on Linux
speed 38400 baud; rows 24; columns 120; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q;
stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc

This is on Solaris
speed 38400 baud; 
rows = 24; columns = 120; ypixels = 0; xpixels = 0;
csdata ?
eucw 1:0:0:0, scrw 1:0:0:0
intr = ^c; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^u;
eof = ^d; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>;
start = ^q; stop = ^s; susp = ^z; dsusp = ^y;
rprnt = ^r; flush = ^o; werase = ^w; lnext = ^v;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -cstopb -hupcl cread -clocal -loblk -crtscts -crtsxoff -parext 
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl -iuclc 
ixon -ixany -ixoff -imaxbel 
isig icanon -xcase echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh 
-tostop echoctl -echoprt echoke -defecho -flusho -pendin iexten 
opost -olcuc onlcr -ocrnl -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel 

Term used, on Linux and Solaris both xterm, I change with TERM=dtterm
on Solaris, but nothing change.
This gif show what happen with vim on Solaris
EDIT1: making a terminal reset and also Solaris terminal became good, but it will return bugged after some use so is not a solution.
EDIT2: happen on ssh terminal, on console terminal works fine.

It looks perfectly expected to me. Have you tried piping the output of man wget into a pager? For example more or maybe less?

Is not perfect, is truncated at the middle of screen, my terminal on xfce is configured to scroll and became more big when add more lines, on Solaris seems there is a "limit" or a "quota" of lines.

I don't understand what you're saying. What I can see of the screenshot is the tail end of a virtual page of paper with several empty lines

Can you show an example where lines are actually and evidently missing? The picture you're linking to at the end seems to show exactly the same text as your example of a truncated text.

Is this happening over a serial terminal or over ssh? I've seen it happen with ncurses programs on Linux reconfiguring the serial tty.

Over ssh, now I try serial. On serial works fine. If you put your comment as answer I will vote your answer positive because you suggest me that was ncurses problem.

On both systems, the stty -a information indicates the terminal window should be 120x24 characters in size (rows 24; columns 120 on Linux, and rows = 24; columns = 120). On your Linux screenshot, that seems to be the truth. But in your Solaris screenshot, there are clearly more than 24 lines, and the stty -a output at that time should reflect that fact. The Solaris output seems to be truncated after the 24th line, so the shell and any other programs you're running are just taking the terminal size indicated by stty -a as an absolute truth.
When you resize your terminal window, the terminal emulator process (e.g. xterm in your case) is supposed to send a window change signal (SIGWINCH) to the process(es) running within that terminal window to tell them the window size has changed. Then the process(es) should update both the stty settings and their internal idea of the display size.
When complications like remote terminal connections and old commercial Unix software are added to the mix, sometimes it can happen that the signal fails to get delivered, or only gets delivered to the process that is currently active on the terminal at the time.
So when you connect to a remote host, login, start up a text editor, and then resize the window to better see what you're editing, the editor might get the message that the window size has changed and adapt... but once you exit the editor and start some other program, like man for example, you might see that the shell did not get the SIGWINCH, and still has the wrong window size information in the stty information and/or in the COLUMNS and LINES environment variables... and as the shell's environment variables are inherited by its child processes, the shell is now propagating incorrect information about the window size.
Yes, the correct way to fix this would be to ensure all relevant programs deal with SIGWINCH and terminal size changes properly... but unfortunately old buggy software seems to never completely vanish.
The usual workaround would be to exit the full-screen program exhibiting the incorrect behavior, and run eval $(resize) (or equivalent) in the shell you used to start it. It should re-probe for the current window size and adjust the stty information and the above-mentioned environment variables to match the actual window size. In other words, it manually forces the things that should have happened automatically as a result of SIGWINCH.
Sometimes a simple resize may suffice; but using the eval $(resize) form also causes the shell's COLUMNS and LINES environment variables to be updated... and occasionally you'll be using some old software that uses the values in those environment variables and expects them to be correct.
After that, it might be good to keep in mind something like "I'm in a system with less-than-perfect SIGWINCH handling; it would be best to adjust terminal window sizes only when there is just a shell prompt on the terminal, and not when some full-screen program is running."
(I seem to recall that old Solaris versions used to have quite old default implementations of vi and more... and the latter was probably also used as the default pager by man and the like. I would not be too surprised if their SIGWINCH handling was less than perfect.)

Complete and good explanation, thanks. I have found this problem happen (even with ssh -t) after a lot on "man", in those days I'm studying the good old solaris 10 and I use a lot the man command.

Solution found. After user suggestion that happen on ssh, I tried
ssh -t solaris10

Seems to works fine.

What command  were you previously using instead of this?

I used ssh without -t option

The stty settings here are irrelevant.  What you need to check is the terminal type settings in $TERM which might not even be set if -t fixed the problem.  As to why -t wasn't default, that depends on your pre-ssh local environment which you didn't describe at all.  If you still need an answer, add those details to your question.

$TERM is irrelevant.  The issue is that when ssh connection doesn't allocate a terminal connection, it won't do NAWS (negotiation about window size).  This question is probably a duplicate.
